# Contacts export only contains one entry

Tags: search, export

In CiviCRM 4.7.5 and 4.7.6 (tested in both) we have a problem exporting event participants.

If you 'find participants' > search results screen > select all records, and then click 'export participants' no matter what options you select on the next screen (primary fields vs selected fields), only one record is exported.

The same behaviour happens if you use the advanced search tool to export any list of contacts - eg a list of members, so I think there may be a bug in the search results screen, as this is used by both of the above routes.

Using Event Reports > Event Participant List > Export to CSV will export a full list of participants, but doesn't have our custom fields.

Is anyone else seeing this behaviour / bug?

Comment: I seen the same bug in the WordPress version 4.7.5 on our test site and 4.7.7 on the demo site. It works fine on 4.7.3 on our production site. This should be reported as a bug in the issue tracker. Will you do that?

Comment: It also happens in Drupal, so it's not exclusive for WordPress. I tested it too in the demo site and it doesn't works.

Comment: See also: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11191/exports-in-4-7-6-are-not-working-correctly/

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment, not an answer.  Also, as mentioned by Albert V, the bug has been reported: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18378

Comment: I have the same situation here, using Joomla!. The fix @ https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8138 worked great.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in CiviCRM which has since been fixed. You can upgrade to version 4.7.7 to fix your site.

See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18378