# Exports in 4.7.6 are not working correctly

Tags: 4.7, issues, export

If I do any type of search and then try to export my search results, the export CSV only contains one record.  Even if the search finds hundreds of records, and I tell the export to export them all, I only get one record in the CSV.

It was working fine for us on 4.6, but as soon as we upgraded to 4.7 this broke.

Are other people having this issue?  Anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this?

Any help at all would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug and will be updated in the next release. In the meantime, you can [use this PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8138) to fix.

[Further info on Jira](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18378).